# How to convert <tr id> to <div id>?

Tags: html, asp.net

Hi I have the following code in asp.net page

```
<tr id="XYZ" runat = "server">
  <td>body</td>
</tr>
```

I was trying to convert this into the div span format

```
<div class="ui-class" id="XYZ">
<span>body</span>
</div>
```

In the designer file i changed the datatype of the Div id from Html Generic to as followed

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow XYZ
```

When i am trying to access this id(XYZ) from my aspx.cs file it is giving me null.
Can anybody help me out here?

EDIT as nothingisnecessary pointed out i tried

```
<div class="ui-class" id="XYZ" runat="server">
<span>body</span>
</div>
```

Also changed the Datatype back to

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl
```

but it's still the same.

Comment: how about `ctrl` + `H`??

Comment: What does ctrl+H do?

Comment: ctrl+H is just find and replace, but that's not helpful because you have already modified the control's class in your .designer file. Notice how your `TR` has `runat="server"` but your `div` does not.. see full explanation below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `runat="server"` attribute to make it a server control so that it can be used in the codebehind.

Try adding `runat="server"` to your `div` as follows:

```
<div class="ui-class" id="XYZ" runat="server">
<span>body</span>
</div>
```

Without the `runat="server"` attribute ASP.NET won't treat your controls as server controls (won't add them to the control tree, serialize to viewstate, etc.), and won't allow you to manipulate them from the codebehind (with a few exceptions that I am ignoring for sake of simplicity).

Also your code doesn't actually show the `HtmlGenericControl` control. You would need this instead:

```
protected System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl XYZ;
```

The `protected` access modifier (or could be `public`) is important because the ASPX gets compiled to a class that is a *subclass* of the codebehind that it inherits from. The codebehind typically *declares* the controls, and the ASPX *instantiates* them (basically it does `XYZ = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl()` automatically for you). The declaration and instantiation of `XYZ` is what makes it non-null when accessed in the code behind.

If you still have problems you may want to verify that your ASPX is not using `XYZ` as a dynamic control or inside of a databound control, such as a `Repeater` since those would be handled differently (inside of an `OnItemDataBound` handler, for example).

Comment: i tried it. the designer files gives the following statement when i hover my mouse over the tag in the id.
"its not initialized.default value will be null"